# How to attach to remote R kernel in VS Code?

Tags: r, ssh, conda, visual-studio-code

I am using both `R` and `python` for a research project. The computations and all analyses are done in a remote server which I access using SSH. I do not have root privileges to the server.

I have a Conda virtual environment for the project. My usual workflow is connecting to the server through the SSH features of Visual Studio Code and then editing code and running it in the terminal iteratively (using [the **Remote - SSH** extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) from Microsoft). When editing Python scripts, everything works great: I can edit the files and run them in the terminal with no error messages and so on.

However, as soon as I start editing an R script, I get some weird error messages although I believe R is correctly set up. See the output of a quick check (out of a simple Terminal shell):

[image]

The Conda environment I am working on is `r_conda`. It shows that it sees `R` and it's loading it from the correct binary. Even `radian` seems to be correctly installed in the Conda environment.

When I open an R file in VS Code, I get the following errors:

[image]

I am using [this R extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r).

I have already edited the settings of the extension to point it to the correct binaries:

[image]

**Does anyone know what is going on? How to solve this?**

---

Following the suggestion from @merv, here is what is installed in the `r_conda` environment:

```
(r_conda) [rgr6291@klc0201 ~]$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/r_conda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.36.1               h193b22a_2    conda-forge
binutils_linux-64         2.36                 hf3e587d_4    conda-forge
bwidget                   1.9.14               ha770c72_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.10.8            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            ha00ac49_1009    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
curl                      7.81.0               h494985f_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            hba837de_1005    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h0708190_1    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.10               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
gcc_impl_linux-64         9.4.0               h03d3576_11    conda-forge
gcc_linux-64              9.4.0                h391b98a_4    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h73d1719_1008    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    9.4.0               h0003116_11    conda-forge
gfortran_linux-64         9.4.0                hf0ab688_4    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.13            h58526e2_1001    conda-forge
gsl                       2.7                  he838d99_0    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         9.4.0               h03d3576_11    conda-forge
gxx_linux-64              9.4.0                h0316aca_4    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  3.2.0                hb4a5f5f_0    conda-forge
icu                       69.1                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
jbig                      2.1               h7f98852_2003    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              he073ed8_15    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.2               h48eae69_3    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.36.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
lerc                      3.0                  h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           12_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           12_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.81.0               h494985f_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.8                  h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     9.4.0               hd854feb_11    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0              h1d223b6_11    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            11.2.0              h69a702a_11    conda-forge
libgfortran5              11.2.0              h5c6108e_11    conda-forge
libglib                   2.70.2               h174f98d_1    conda-forge
libgomp                   11.2.0              h1d223b6_11    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           12_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               ha19adfc_1    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.18          pthreads_h8fe5266_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h21135ba_2    conda-forge
libsanitizer              9.4.0               h79bfe98_11    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               ha35d2d1_2    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  9.4.0               hd854feb_11    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0              he4da1e4_11    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.3.0                h6f004c6_2    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.1                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.12               h885dcf4_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.11            h36c2ea0_1013    conda-forge
lineedit                  0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
make                      4.3                  hd18ef5c_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h58526e2_4    conda-forge
openssl                   3.0.0                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.17                 h7f98852_0    conda-forge
pango                     1.50.3               h9967ed3_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.37                h032f7d1_0    conda-forge
pip                       21.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.10.2          h543edf9_0_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
r-askpass                 1.1               r41hcfec24a_2    conda-forge
r-assertthat              0.2.1             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-backports               1.4.1             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-base                    4.1.2                h2553ce4_1    conda-forge
r-base64enc               0.1_3           r41hcfec24a_1004    conda-forge
r-bayestestr              0.11.5            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-bit                     4.0.4             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-bit64                   4.0.5             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-blob                    1.2.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-brio                    1.1.3             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-broom                   0.7.11            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-callr                   3.7.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-cellranger              1.1.0           r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-checkmate               2.0.0             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-cli                     3.1.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-clipr                   0.7.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-colorspace              2.0_2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-cpp11                   0.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-crayon                  1.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-curl                    4.3.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-data.table              1.14.2            r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-datawizard              0.2.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-dbi                     1.1.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-dbplyr                  2.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-desc                    1.4.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-diffobj                 0.3.5             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-digest                  0.6.29            r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-dplyr                   1.0.7             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-dtplyr                  1.2.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ellipsis                0.3.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-evaluate                0.14              r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-fansi                   1.0.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-farver                  2.1.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-fastmap                 1.1.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-forcats                 0.5.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-fs                      1.5.2             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-gargle                  1.2.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-gdtools                 0.2.3             r41h42e24d8_0    conda-forge
r-generics                0.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ggplot2                 3.3.5             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ggsci                   2.9             r41hc72bb7e_1003    conda-forge
r-glue                    1.6.0             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-googledrive             2.0.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-googlesheets4           1.0.0             r41h785f33e_0    conda-forge
r-gtable                  0.3.0             r41hc72bb7e_3    conda-forge
r-haven                   2.4.3             r41h2713e49_0    conda-forge
r-here                    1.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-highr                   0.9               r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-hms                     1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-htmltools               0.5.2             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-httr                    1.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ids                     1.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-insight                 0.15.0            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-isoband                 0.2.5             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-jquerylib               0.1.4             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-jsonlite                1.7.3             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-kableextra              1.3.4             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-knitr                   1.37              r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-labeling                0.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-lattice                 0.20_45           r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-lifecycle               1.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-lubridate               1.8.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-magrittr                2.0.1             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-mass                    7.3_55            r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-matrix                  1.4_0             r41he454529_0    conda-forge
r-mgcv                    1.8_38            r41he454529_0    conda-forge
r-mime                    0.12              r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-modelr                  0.1.8             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-modelsummary            0.9.5             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-munsell                 0.5.0           r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-nlme                    3.1_155           r41h859d828_0    conda-forge
r-openssl                 1.4.6             r41he82ab30_0    conda-forge
r-parameters              0.16.0            r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-performance             0.8.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-pillar                  1.6.4             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-pkgconfig               2.0.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-pkgload                 1.2.4             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-praise                  1.0.0           r41hc72bb7e_1005    conda-forge
r-prettyunits             1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-processx                3.5.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-progress                1.2.2             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-ps                      1.6.0             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-purrr                   0.3.4             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-r6                      2.5.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rappdirs                0.3.3             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-rcolorbrewer            1.1_2           r41h785f33e_1003    conda-forge
r-rcpp                    1.0.8             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-readr                   2.1.1             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-readxl                  1.3.1             r41h2713e49_4    conda-forge
r-rematch                 1.0.1           r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-rematch2                2.1.2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-reprex                  2.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rlang                   0.4.12            r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-rmarkdown               2.11              r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-rprojroot               2.0.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rstudioapi              0.13              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rvest                   1.0.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-sandwich                3.0_1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-scales                  1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-selectr                 0.4_2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-stringi                 1.7.6             r41h337692f_1    conda-forge
r-stringr                 1.4.0             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-svglite                 2.0.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-sys                     3.4               r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-systemfonts             1.0.3             r41hef9c87a_0    conda-forge
r-tables                  0.9.6             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-testthat                3.1.1             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-tibble                  3.1.6             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-tidyr                   1.1.4             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-tidyselect              1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-tidyverse               1.3.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-tinytex                 0.36              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-tzdb                    0.2.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-utf8                    1.2.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-uuid                    1.0_3             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-vctrs                   0.3.8             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-viridislite             0.4.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-vroom                   1.5.7             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-waldo                   0.3.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-webshot                 0.5.2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-withr                   2.4.3             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-xfun                    0.29              r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-xml2                    1.3.3             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-yaml                    2.2.1             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-zoo                     1.8_9             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
radian                    0.5.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rchitect                  0.3.35                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.1                  h46c0cb4_0    conda-forge
sed                       4.8                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
setuptools                60.5.0                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.37.0               h9cd32fc_0    conda-forge
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                he073ed8_15    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.11               h27826a3_1    conda-forge
tktable                   2.10                 hb7b940f_3    conda-forge
tzdata                    2021e                he74cb21_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.7.2                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.2.1                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h36c2ea0_1013    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.1                ha95c52a_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Please add details on what is installed in the `r_conda` environment.

Comment: @merv just added the list of what is installed. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Are you sure radian is supposed to be installed in the R environment? (I'm very skeptical of anything that leads to R and Python being installed in the same environment). More to your question though, are you sure the `~/` is interpreted correctly? Maybe try giving the full path, i.e., `/home/rgr6291/.conda/envs/r_conda/bin/R`

Comment: @merv I tried to use create another environment without radian and the same problem remains. I also used absolute paths and it didn't work. I opened a Github issue about this since I believe my setup, although somewhat specific, might be representative for a wider array of researchers: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/946#issuecomment-1015818384